# put today + 3 working days (as default value) in a Sql datetime field

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

i want to set the default value in a sql server 2005 datetime field to today + 3 working days.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll want to set your "Default Value or Binding" to one of the following:

```
SELECT (dateadd(day,(3),getdate()))

SELECT (dateadd(day,(3),cast(floor(cast(getdate() as float)) as datetime)))
```

The first one will give you today's date *and time* and add exactly 3 days to it (so you'll be let with the time value in there as well).

The second will give you today's date with a time value of 00:00:00 (i.e. midnight) and add exact 3 days to it.

**EDIT:**

Ah..  I see you said "working days".   Well, my example will give you 3 *chronological* days, but to calculate 3 working days will be incredibly hard since the very definition of "working day" can be slightly ambiguous.  For example, I'm going to make the assumption that a "working day" is the standard Monday to Friday.   However, what happens when one of those Mondays is a national holiday?   In the UK, that can change each year (i.e. it's not always on the exact same date).

Calculating "working days" is difficult, and is usually best done via a lookup table using a function (either in code or in SQL).

Here's one link that may provide insight into this...  It's not necessarily pretty, though!  :)

[SQL Server - UDF for Business Days Calculation](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20030626.asp)

Comment: `GETDATE()+3` is the same as `dateadd(day,(3),getdate())`

Comment: Can i use this udf in a default value for a column?

Comment: @Michel - Yes, you can use a UDF (user defined function) as a "default" value in a table column.  Make sure you specify the "full" name, though (i.e. dbo.myUDF rather than myUDF)

Answer (score 3):

Hard. SQL defaults are to be simple - and working days are PRETTY complicated to do. Not only do you need to think of day of week, but also of.... holidays.

If you have a holiday table, you could do it with a custom function and/or a triggered stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

This query stands good for fetching the values between current date and its next 3 dates

SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE columName BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY)

This will eventually add extra 3 days of buffer to the current date.